# how to refresh a parent window on close of child window in windows application

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I have a parent window and a child window. On saving on child window I get alert message and I press ok.On pressing of ok my child gets closed and parent gets updated but the previous object on the parent form still their.
Now how can I close the older parent page [before updating].

On click of ok I need to return to updated  parent page only.

Conclusion :  But I am getting both older parent and new parent window on click of ok.

On click of ok code as follows:

```
Me.Close() 'for closing the child window.            
Dim frmparent As Form = New frmDomain 'for opening the parent window with updation.
frmDomain2.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen 'to open it in center.
frmDomain2.MdiParent = frmMain
frmDomain2.Show()
```

Answer (score 2):

The way that you update the parent depends on the way that you open your child window, modal or modeless:

- **Modal**: your child window gets the focus and blocks the parent.

  - You have to open it using `childForm.ShowDialog()`
  - The lines after that won't execute until the child form is closed. This means, you can call your update method right after the `ShowDialog()`

This way:

```
Public Sub SomeMethod() 
  'Code in the parent:
  Dim childForm as New MyChildForm()
  childForm.ShowDialog()
  Me.UpdateParentMethod()
  'other stuff the parent has to do
End
```

- **Modeless** : your child window does not block the parent.

  - You use `child.Show()` to open the child as modeless.
  - In the parent, the lines after that are executed and the parent continues running in a normal way.
  - In order to detect when the child form has been closed, you'll have to subscribe to its OnFormClosed event from the parent, and execute there your refesh code.

This way:

```
Public Sub SomeMethod() 
  Dim childForm as New MyChildForm()
  AddHandler childForm.FormClosed, AddressOf ChildForm_FormClosed
  childForm.Show()
  'other stuff the parent has to do
End

Public Sub ChildForm_FormClosed(sender as Object, e as FormClosedEventArgs)
  Me.UpdateParentMethod()
End
```

More info:

- [Modal and modeless forms in Windows Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984358(v=vs.71).aspx).
- [Event OnFormClosed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosed(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you call your window a "child window", then you had to call it from a "parent window".

If I understand your issue correctly, from within you called your chiled, put a refresh function *at the end* of the function where you declare your child. I.e.:

```
Dim FrmChild As Form = New ChildForm 
FrmChild .MdiParent = Me
FrmChild.Show()

call MyUpdateFormFunction()  -- << this will be executed after FrmChild will be closed
```